# Regular Expression Commas and Columns

Tags: .net, regex

I have an issue while parsing my Solr Queries that I pass on the querystring:

The values I end up having to work with look like this:

> ed_deliveryMethod:Face to
>   Face,ed_location:Alexandria,VA,ed_delivery:Onsite

I need a regex that would parse a key value pair:

- ed_deliveryMethod:Face to Face
- ed_location:Alexandria,VA
- ed_delivery:Onsite

So I need a regex to parse

> FacetName:FacetValue

I was doing a split by commas but the comma on the location is throwing things off.

The last comma is optional since there might be just one filter.

I did try a lot of things before asking this question but no success. I'm not good at regex as you can see.

```
((?<Facet>.+):(?<FacetValue>.+),)+
```

Comment: why are you parsing Solr queries? can you give more information about the underlying issue, what you're trying to solve?

Comment: So I build my query string to be ?filter=category:car&filter=category:motorcycle.   So when I get the query string in .net it comes to be as a comma separated value.  QueryString[filter] will be = category:car,category:motorcyle.  I then use those to build my solr query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
(?<Facet>\w+):(?<FacetValue>.+?)(?=,\w+:|$)
```

Maybe you need to adjust `\w` to contain all allowed charactes of your keys.

Comment: 0-9 and _  is included in `\w`, so `\w` is the same than `[\w0-9_]`

Answer (score 1):

Use `QueryString.GetValues(key)`, it returns an array of values.

E.g. if you have `&filter=category:car&filter=category:motorcycle` as you mentioned in a comment, and you call `QueryString.GetValues("filter")` you get an array with elements `"category:car"` and `"category:motorcycle"`. Then split each element by `:`, etc.
[No regex needed](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247).

Comment: Oh, good! I changed to code to use GetValues(). Will leave the answer to Peter as my question specifically related to Regex but you are correct. This approach is much better for my scenario. Thanks again.